# build eclipse project when antoher project is requied

Tags: eclipse, build, project

I had wrote an app( android A) and I would like to build. The problem is the following: I had another android project(B), witch I want to start from the "A" one when the user click on an icon. I had added to the "A" build path the "B" project, but it isn't works. As I trying to build the "A" the app going down and said: "Class B not found on com.pack.BMain,".

Any idea or tutorial ? I could not found neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your project > Properties > Android:
At the right side of the pop window, find Library part, click Add button to add project you want to reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try. As you mentioned, make sure B is in A's build path (Right click on A in package explorer, **Properties/Java Build Path/Projects/Add**). You should also make sure that your run configuration includes both projects. Go to **Run Configurations/Your configuration/Plug-ins/** and add A, then hit **Add Required Plug-ins**, or add B manually. Make sure **Validate Plugins** returns no errors.

Comment: Hey Dude!
I had found the plungins (but not in the run config, there was noting for me) and added as you wrote:( but still don't works!
Thank for you advice, I think I made one step forward!